# Improve readability of very large constants in C++

Tags: c++

In C++, sometimes you want to declare large numbers. Sometimes it's hard to see if you have the right number of zeroes.

```
const long long VERY_LARGE_NUMBER = 300000000000;
```

In a language like OCaml, you can separate numbers with underscores to improve readability.

```
let x = 300_000_000_000;;
```

Is there a similar mechanism in C++? I have seen things like `= 1 << 31` for powers of 2, but what about for very large powers of 10? Sometimes you're declaring very large numbers (e.g. array bounds in competition programming) and you want to be confident that your declared array size is correct.

I can think of something like:

```
const long long VERY_LARGE_NUMBER = 3 * (1 << (11 * 10 / 3));
```

...which abuses `1<<10 ~= 1000` get close to 3 with 11 zeroes, but it's verbose and not exact.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Digit_separators

Comment: Sometimes hexadecimal representations help. Otherwise, only way I can think of is putting a comment above the declaration!!

Comment: You can also use scientific notation for constants i.e. `const long long VERY_LARGE_NUMBER=3e11;`

Comment: @Mat great and nice c++14 feature

Comment: would something like this help?
`const long long VERY_LARGE_NUMBER = 3e10;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about

```
const long long VERY_LARGE_NUMBER =  (long long) 300 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
```

Comment: This is how I accomplish readability more often than not.  It looks like C++14 has exactly what you want if your environment supports it.  This works everywhere and efficiently too ;)

Answer (score 4):

Since C++14, integer literal supports the use of `'` as a delimiter. For example, `unsigned long long l2 = 18'446'744'073'709'550'592llu;`. See [this cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) for the details. Also, you may consider using scientific notation, like `123e4`. Such literals are [floating point literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal). But you can convert them to integer types.

Comment: From some perspective, a floating point literal would be _even less readable_, because it should immediately trigger worries about loss of precision.